# How can we modify the width of the columns in gridlayout in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I created a grid layout with 5 columns in a row. I am stuck with modifying the width of each of hte columns. For example, in some cases i want to display only the last 2. However in other time,I want to display only the first 2 columns.

```
let gridContainer = createGridLayout('grid_layout','*,*,*,*,*','*')
columns = gridContainer.getColumns();
console.log(columns[0].value);
```

Comment: What you mean by modifying width? You want to decide on number of columns dynamically? If you want to split the space equally between columns, you have to just place the same number of asterisks (`*`) as the number of columns.

Comment: yaa thanks for the information. I updated the value and used * to define the width of the columns..